# Qemu share folder - 9pnet_virtio: no channels available for device

Tags: linux, virtualization, qemu, virtio

I try to run a qemu virtual machine having a folder shared with host. No matter what I do, I have always the same error: `9pnet_virtio: no channels available for device share`.

Host machine is under Linux.

Kernel was compiled with all 9P and virtio options enabled (https://wiki.qemu.org/Documentation/9psetup).

Here's my script to run qemu:

```
#! /bin/bash

HDA=archlinux.img
HDB=myHome.img
KERNEL=linux/arch/x86/boot/bzImage

if [ -n "${KDB}" ]; then
    KGD_WAIT='kgdbwait'
fi

CMDLINE="root=/dev/sda1 rw vga=792 console=ttyS0 kgdboc=ttyS1 ${KGD_WAIT}"

FLAGS="--enable-kvm -s"
VIRTFS+=" --virtfs local,path=./share/,mount_tag=share,security_model=passthrough,id=share "

exec qemu-system-x86_64 ${FLAGS} \
     -hda "${HDA}" -hdb "${HDB}" \
     ${VIRTFS} \
     -net user -net nic \
     -serial stdio -serial tcp::1234,server,nowait \
     -boot c -m 1G \
     -kernel "${KERNEL}" -append "${CMDLINE}"
```

When I mount the folder manually (https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/9p_virtio)

```
mkdir share_folder
mount -t 9p -o trans=virtio,version=9p2000.L share share_folder
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Here is an automated QEMU+ Buildroot setup that uses 9P successfully: https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/tree/8815312cad053d0284c4d91bfbf36a1e9ea207af#9p

Answer (score 3):

Resolved for me (with an ubuntu 18.04 host and 14.04 guest) by adding theses modules:

- `virtio_input`
- `9pnet`
- `9pnet_virtio`

into guest file `/etc/initramfs-tools/modules`.

***Don't forget*** to upadate initramfs for your kernel(s) after add:

`update-initramfs -uk <kernel|all>`

Comment: This also solved for me a problem on WSL with a startup error saying not having permission to mount a specific drive

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was failing due to missing **virtio_pci** module and I fixed it with:

modprobe virtio_pci